# How to call a directive from a controller

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a directive which is depending on input. I want to call that directive from angular controller when ever that input changed. Here is my directive.

```
    var app = angular.module('App', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('fcController', function($scope, fcService, $uibModal) {
    $scope.formatType = '1';
});

app.directive('fcsaNumber', function($filter) {
    var addCommasToInteger, controlKeys, hasMultipleDecimals, isNotControlKey, isNotDigit, isNumber, makeIsValid, makeMaxDecimals, makeMaxDigits, makeMaxNumber, makeMinNumber;
    isNumber = function(val) {
        return !isNaN(parseFloat(val)) && isFinite(val);
    };
    isNotDigit = function(which) {
        return which < 45 || which > 57 || which === 47;
    };
    controlKeys = [0, 8, 13];
    isNotControlKey = function(which) {
        return controlKeys.indexOf(which) === -1;
    };
    hasMultipleDecimals = function(val) {
        return (val != null) && val.toString().split('.').length > 2;
    };
    makeMaxDecimals = function(maxDecimals) {
        var regexString, validRegex;
        if (maxDecimals > 0) {
            regexString = "^-?\\d*\\.?\\d{0," + maxDecimals + "}$";
        } else {
            regexString = "^-?\\d*$";
        }
        validRegex = new RegExp(regexString);
        return function(val) {
            return validRegex.test(val);
        };
    };
    makeMaxNumber = function(maxNumber) {
        return function(val, number) {
            return number <= maxNumber;
        };
    };
    makeMinNumber = function(minNumber) {
        return function(val, number) {
            return number >= minNumber;
        };
    };
    makeMaxDigits = function(maxDigits) {
        var validRegex;
        validRegex = new RegExp("^-?\\d{0," + maxDigits + "}(\\.\\d*)?$");
        return function(val) {
            return validRegex.test(val);
        };
    };
    makeIsValid = function(options) {
        var validations;
        validations = [];
        if (options.maxDecimals != null) {
            validations.push(makeMaxDecimals(options.maxDecimals));
        }
        if (options.max != null) {
            validations.push(makeMaxNumber(options.max));
        }
        if (options.min != null) {
            validations.push(makeMinNumber(options.min));
        }
        if (options.maxDigits != null) {
            validations.push(makeMaxDigits(options.maxDigits));
        }
        return function(val) {
            var i, number, _i, _ref;
            if (!isNumber(val)) {
                return false;
            }
            if (hasMultipleDecimals(val)) {
                return false;
            }
            number = Number(val);
            for (i = _i = 0, _ref = validations.length; 0 <= _ref ? _i < _ref : _i > _ref; i = 0 <= _ref ? ++_i : --_i) {
                if (!validations[i](val, number)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        };
    };
    addCommasToInteger = function(val) {
        var commas, decimals, wholeNumbers;
        decimals = val.indexOf('.') == -1 ? '.00' : val.replace(/^\d+(?=\.)/, '');
        wholeNumbers = val.replace(/(\.\d+)$/, '');
        commas = wholeNumbers.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1,');
        return "" + commas + decimals.substring(0, 3);
    };
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            options: '@fcsaNumber',
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            var isValid, options;
            options = {};
            if (scope.options != null) {
                options = scope.$eval(scope.options);
            }
            isValid = makeIsValid(options);
            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewVal) {
                var noCommasVal;
                noCommasVal = viewVal.replace(/,/g, '');
                if (isValid(noCommasVal) || !noCommasVal) {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('fcsaNumber', true);
                    return noCommasVal;
                } else {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('fcsaNumber', false);
                    return void 0;
                }
            });
            ngModelCtrl.$formatters.push(function(val) {
                if ((options.nullDisplay != null) && (!val || val === '')) {
                    return options.nullDisplay;
                }
                if ((val == null) || !isValid(val)) {
                    return val;
                }
                ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('fcsaNumber', true);
                val = addCommasToInteger(val.toString());
                if (options.key == 1) {
                    options.prepend = 'S/.';
                }
                if (options.key == 2) {
                    options.prepend = '$';
                }
                if (options.prepend != null) {
                    val = "" + options.prepend + val;
                }
                if (options.append != null) {
                    val = "" + val + options.append;
                }
                return val;
            });
            elem.on('blur', function() {
                var formatter, viewValue, _i, _len, _ref;
                viewValue = ngModelCtrl.$modelValue;
                if ((viewValue == null) || !isValid(viewValue)) {
                    return;
                }
                _ref = ngModelCtrl.$formatters;
                for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
                    formatter = _ref[_i];
                    viewValue = formatter(viewValue);
                }
                ngModelCtrl.$viewValue = viewValue;
                return ngModelCtrl.$render();
            });
            elem.on('focus', function() {
                var val;
                val = elem.val();
                if (options.prepend != null) {
                    val = val.replace(options.prepend, '');
                }
                if (options.append != null) {
                    val = val.replace(options.append, '');
                }
                elem.val(val.replace(/,/g, ''));
                return elem[0].select();
            });
            if (options.preventInvalidInput === true) {
                return elem.on('keypress', function(e) {
                    if (isNotDigit(e.which && isNotControlKey(e.which))) {
                        return e.preventDefault();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type ="text" ng-model ="currency" fcsa-number="{key : {{formatType}}}">
```

Here `$scope.formatType = '1';` is the input. If this formatType changed then That directive need to call. How can I call that directive from angular controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a watcher inside the link function you have written that will watch for the change of `fcsa-number` and group everything that you needs to be run into a function and call it inside the watcher .

```
link: function(scope,elem,attr,ctrl){
 scope.$watch('options', function(){
  // do your stuff
 });
```

Comment: it's not fulfilling my requirement

Comment: @RakeshReddy My bad , As the isolated scope variable you have mentioned for the directive is named options , `options`is what you should be watching for changes . You can group all your logic that you want to call inside a function and call the function inside this watcher . It should work .

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$broadcast` to call directive from the controller

```
.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.$watch('formatType', function() {
        $scope.$broadcast("call_dir")
    })
})
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: {
        options: '@fcsaNumber',
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        var isValid, options;
        options = {};
        scope.$on('call_dir', function(ev) {
            //your code
        })
    };
```

Comment: fine... Let me try once. and get you back

Comment: may i know what is ev here

Comment: it is the event. by default broadcast send the event as the first parameter

Comment: can we have a chat box

Comment: It is not posible to create chat box, bcz of low reputations can you create chat box

Comment: it's not fulfilling my requirement